# How to center Lyx code?

Tags: lyx, center

I am writing some Python code in Lyx and since it Python uses indentation, some of the code goes past the right margin.

I have 5 centimetre margins on each side, but the code only ignores the right one, the left margin is left intact. This makes the code look shifted to the right. I would prefer that instead of skipping 2 centimetres on the right, for example, the code skipped 1 centimetre on the left margin and the other on the right margin, so it looked more centred.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It is not clear what are you doing  and therefore what you should do. Nonetheless, consideruse a minipage (Insert > Box > Frameless) With a right click you can set the witdth  and alignement of this box.